# Javascript: How to insert a row at an index to a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am novice programmer in javascript. Kindly guide me in the right path.

Below is a 3D array of size **2 x 3 x 3**

```
"items": [ [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ], [ [10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18] ] ]
```

Now, I need to insert a row, something like `[ [19,20,21], [22,23,24], [25,26,27] ]` **at an index 1 or 2**.

I tried with [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function, but all in vain.

Being a multi dimensional array, I don't know what value goes into the *itemN* parameter of the *splice* function.

```
items.splice(insertIndex, 0, `????`);
```

How can I accomplish it? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use splice with deleteCount 0 (second parameter). as thrid param you enter the 2-dimensional array you want to add.

```
var items = [ [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ], [ [10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18] ] ];
var add = [ [19,20,21], [22,23,24], [25,26,27] ];
items.splice(insertIndex, 0, add);
```

working example here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uctqgvd/1/)

Comment: Well i am confused. The current `items` array has already value at index 1. Then why did it shifted that value to index 2 and added the new value at index 1?

Comment: @HarshMakani - The splice function will insert the `items` at the specified index

Answer (score 1):

You can pass complete array which you want to insert to [**splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) parameter, like:

```
items.splice(2, 0,[ [19,20,21], [22,23,24], [25,26,27] ]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/617rs7aL/)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good.

I make an demo to insert middle row in angular as reference.

I share for whom concerned.

```
    textarray = [
        [{ text: "Content 1" }, { text: "Content 2" }],
        [{ text: "Content 3" }, { text: "Content 4" }]
      ];
      rowindex = 1;
      insertmiddle() {
        let size = this.textarray[0].length;
        this.textarray.splice(this.rowindex, 0, 
             Array(size).fill({ text: "Content", tag: "Content" }));
      }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-insert-row-matrix